# Caps Lock not working on 10.6.7

Tags: snow-leopard, caps-lock

my caps lock key doesn't work. I changed the keyboard and it also doesn't work with the new one. Now, every other key works fine, and if I go to pref pane> keyboard and replace caps lock with say option key, then it lights it up, so I know that's not broken.

This is an old macbook pro, 15 inch, 2ghz, but with Leopard worked fine and now it doesn't.

Has anyone come across something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure that your CAPS LOCK key is turned on in your Keyboard Preferences?

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys. Make sure next to Caps Lock, it says Caps Lock and not "No Action".

Also, do you have any 3rd party Keyboard Modification Preference Panes installed, like KeyRemap4MacBook or PCKeyboard Hack? Those can be used in various ways to disable or otherwise alter the CAPS LOCK behavior.

Comment: @ericsocial: thanks, forgot to put that in the original question. Yes, the key is enabled in the pref panel, but doesn't work. However if I replace with say... option key or alt, then it does! Initially I thought it was the physical key that was the problem, but now I got a new keyboard and, well is the same issue.

Comment: Hmm. Have you thought about trying something like PCKeyboardHack and trying to remap the CAPS key to another key and test to see if the Capitalizing funtionality is still working? This definitely sounds like a pretty odd issue. Have you checked to make sure that Text-to-Speech isn't bound to that key? System Preferences -> Speech

Comment: After doing a little research, someone was experiencing this problem and reset the System Management Controller and apparently it started working. You can read up on it [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) that goes a little above my head though. [Here](http://boardreader.com/thread/Snow_Leopard_upgrade_Keyboard_Letters_no_82kjX19xpt.html) is the link to where the idea came from.

Comment: Alternately, if you decide you don't really need a CAPS Lock key, you could [use it to launch Alfred or something similar by remapping it](http://words.tev.net/?p=463). I did, and it's quite awesome, I mean how often do you really need that CAPS Lock?